# Class Scope with method called from subclass JS

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have a subclass that does some validation stuff that calls a method in the parent class that extends it, this is working in all places except when I need to access the local scope in the parent class, see example below

subclass

```
export default class ElementEvent extends Core {
  constructor(events){
    super(events);

    this.validation = this.validateEvent();
    this.element = this.getElement();
    this.triggered = false;
    this.player = false;
    this.waitForElementDelay = 3000;

    if (this.validation){
      if (this.element){
        this.processEvent();
      } else {
        this.waitForElement();
      }
    }

waitForElement(){
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{
      const el = this.getElement();
      if (el){
         this.element = el;
        this.processEvent();
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, this.waitForElementDelay)
  }
  }
```

parent

```
export default class Reading extends ElementEvent {
  constructor(event) {
    super(event);
    this.readingZoneHeight = 50; 
    this.wordsPerMinute = 300;
    this.timer = 0;
  }

  processEvent() {
    //this.elementEntryPoint = this.getElementEntryPoint();
    //this.elementExitPoint = this.getElementExitPoint();

    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.readingZoneHeight);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      console.log('Inside Event Listener ' + this.readingZoneHeight);
      //this.handleWindowScroll();
    });
  }
}
```

When I console log this is shows a Reading class with all the props it should readingZoneHeight, wordsPerMinute etc but this.readingZoneHeight is undefined, however inside the event listener this.readingHeight is the correct value so not sure whats happening here?

Anyone Help?

Comment: you should've point out where it's undefined. It's like finding needle in  haystack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you are calling the `Reading`'s `processEvent` method from the constructor of the `ElementEvent`. So this is actually called as part of the `super(event)` call in the constructor of the `Reading` class.

And since the `super(event)` happens before you actually assign anything to the `this.readingZoneHeight` it is `undefined` at the time you log it.

Comment: Ahh yes that makes sense, i've moved the props down from the constructor to the processEvent method and it works perfectly :)